# assigning to 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') from incompatible type 'const void' error in c

Tags: c

I have a struct as follows:

```
typedef struct{
  const void* ptr;
  size_t len;
}buf;
```

And, I have created a struct variable data

```
const buf data =
{
    (uint8_t []){
    0x2c, 0xaf, 0x70, 0xcc, 0x92, 0x86, 0x60, 0x7f, 0xbe, 0xe1, 0x22, 0x9c, 
    },
    12
};
```

Now I want to increment the pointer by 4 bytes and assign the value to a uint64_t, but I am getting the above specified error

```
uint64_t getVal = 0;
getVal = *(data.ptr + sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Comment: A "generic pointer" (i.e. `void *`) doesn't have a type, you can't dereference it without casting the pointer.

Comment: And technically you can't perform arithmetic with a `void` pointer, because `void` doesn't have a size. But some compilers let you get away with it by arbitrarily assigning the size 1 to objects of `void` type.

Comment: And when you do cast the pointer, dereferencing it likely will violate strict aliasing, and might even fail entirely with a `SIGBUS` or `SIGSEGV` if the address you're attempting to dereference isn't properly aligned for the type of data you've cast the pointer to.

Comment: "to increment the pointer by 4 bytes and assign the value to a uint64_t" --> that would be `data.ptr + sizeof(uint32_t);`.  No `*`.  Do you really want the sum assigned to `getVal`, or the byte at that location or what?